# What do mouse navigation buttons do in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I know this is an extremely lame question, but I can't seem to find an answer, anywhere.  When I click the navigation thumb buttons on my mouse, the cursor jumps between lines and files in Visual Studio 2010.  I assume this is navigating the code, in some logical pattern.  However, it doesn't appear to be following references, and I don't see what that pattern may be.  If VS2010 *is* following references, then it's doing a horrible job.

**UPDATE:**  The mouse cursor is indeed navigating through C# files.

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/57119/Forward-Backward-Code-Navigation-with-the-Mouse-Th

Comment: @Jacob Thanks, but this doesn't help with C#.  :(  I'll give it a +1 for helping out other languages, though.

Comment: @Mike Did you try that little modification in that addin's code suggested in **Comments and Discussions** section in the bottom? According to that user after adding that line it also worked in C#.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/57119/Forward-Backward-Code-Navigation-with-the-Mouse-Th) says

> Visual Studio 2010 lacks support to navigate in the source code using
>   the mouse thumb buttons in the languages C++, Visual Basic and F#.

Comment: Yes, this is why I am baffled by the lack of feature documentation and support in C#.  VS is obviously doing something, but what that something is isn't obvious.